# Second Nintendo Switch, share games and local play?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I now have 2 switch consoles, one permanently docked and the new one potentially for travel but mainly at home in a different room. I buy most of my games digitally.

I primarily want to play local wirelessly with my partner. I also want my new switch to be able to use games I have purchased, they are both my switch's.

My understanding is I should make my new console the primary console for my account and then play on that console with a different user. That way my docked switch can also use games from my original account while connected to the internet.

If true, what does that mean for local wireless play?

For instance games like animal crossing and stardew valley. I am happy to buy the game twice for the 2 accounts, that is not my concern. If need be I'd forget about putting my original account on the new switch just to get local wireless play working.

I'm wary about being able to buy the game again for the second account as it is already installed and playable but not multiplayer like I want. I also don't know if shared saves would be a problem. Pretty happy to not share saves across the 2 accounts at all.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it.

I made my original account have the new console as its primary. We can both play animal crossing at the same time individually. Original console playing as original account, new console using a new account.

Understandably we cannot play local wireless together on one copy of the game.

"Error code 2203-0020

A communication error has occured.

Downloaded software and downloadable content purchased using this nintendo account can only be played on one console at a time."

And the real problem is sadly, my new account on the new switch goes into the eshop knowing the games are purchased from the original account. I cannot buy a second animal crossing digital game. And even if I remove the original account and I buy the game, I think there is a bigger problem:

What I didn't realise is that local wireless turns off wifi. So the original console with the original account not primary, wont be able to play.

The solution I have found is to set it up as described but give both accounts nintendo online. One copy of the game, 2 online accounts, and it works.